# VideoView долгая загрузка видео, как обработать

Tags: java, android, videoview

Есть VideoView, в нем по методу setVideoView(Uri.parse("somePathUrlVideo")) загружается видео через интернет, проблема в том, что загрузка очень долгая, несколько секунд, и на это время интерфейс приложения полностью черный(из-за параметров размера videoView math_parent) после загрузку размер автоматически корректируется и начинается проигрывание. Попытка поставить прогресс бар не сработала, я так понял, видео грузится в другом потоке, а после загрузки приходит callback и videoView меняет размер, так как логи после setVideoView появляются моментально. Если размер ставить фиксированный изначально, то он корректируется относительно высоты videoView и в таком случае занимает не всю ширину, что недопустимо для меня. Подскажите, как решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример кода в Activity:

```
VideoView videoView;
ImageView videoPreview;
ProgressBar videoLoadingProgressBar;
int position = ...;

MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mp.seekTo(position);
    videoLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    videoPreview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mp.start();
});
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("somePathUrlVideo"));
videoLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

соответствующая разметка:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/video_player_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/video_player_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо!